# How to have excel automatically store randomizer data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was given a project to create an excel bingo game 
I already created the 5 cards and have a randomizes representing the "bingo ball"
Is there anyway to have excel create a column and record each number it randomizes?
Due to it constantly changing, each number that is slashed out changes, resorting in a bingo game that can never be one 
sorry for my confusing question 
thank you so much (:

Comment: See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](//superuser.com/q/801609/354511)

Answer (score 1):

If you are randomizing in the cell itself then you have to **copy the numbers and paste them** into the same sheet or another Sheet (tab). That is the most direct way to "store" data. It has to be saved to the hard drive.

It would be most helpful to state whether you are using Cell **Formulas or VBa** code to accomplish this task.

If you are using cell formulae, then you could "record a macro" that copies the cells with the random numbers, then paste them into the same sheet or another sheet. This solution might be above your capabilities, however.

It seems that you are a bit new to Excel and it's capabilities so I will assume that recording a Macro might be a new idea to you. First, if you are using a new version of Excel, your Developer tab's default will be hidden. If you can't see the Developer's Tab, then follow these instructions to make it visible: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php

I don't mention exporting the data into a text document as I don't see the relevancy to the assignment, but there are several ways to "save" data. Saving to a set of cells seems to be the most beneficial method.

**Record a Macro**: If you are up to the challenge. Select the Developers tab and let's create a simple Macro (small sub-routine in the confines of Excel).

1. In Developer's Tab, click Record Macro. Now you are recording a sub-routine.
2. Now select the random numbers by clicking and holding the left-mouse buttons down and dragging over the numbers you wish to save.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to Copy the cells.
4. Click on the new desired location, anywhere on the sheet or another Sheet if you desire; only click on a single cell.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste the cells.
6. Press Stop Recording, while in Developer's Tab.
7. You just created your first sub-routine (Macro).
8. Inspect your Macro: Developer's Tab, Controls section, press View Code. Or by Pressing the shortcut method, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. This opens up the Macro in Edit Mode. You will see the name of your Workbook here and a folder labeled "Modules". Open this folder and Double Click on "Module 1" to view your code. This is what programming a Macro looks like in VBa code. This gives you insight as to what you are performing. The Help files on this are available when this is open in Edit Mode.
9. Run your Macro again: This is the whole point of creating the Macro. There are several ways to accomplish this, by now we are out of the scope of the question. But the easiest way to run the Macro again is: Developer's Tab, Code Section, click Macros, choose the macro to run, then press Run.

**Things to consider about Macros**: There is something called "Use Relative References". To explain, if I say A1, then literally I mean the first call on the Sheet. If I say click any cell, you can simply select any cell. Now if I say relative to the cell you selected, select the adjacent cell to the right. That's the idea of "Use Relative References" in Excel's Macro building. There are so many tutorials out there on the Web and in YouTube. Check them out and in no time you will be an Excel pro. Build a Macro, play with it, use relative references. Build new Macros and experiment. Learn what "Variables" are and how useful they are in Excel; how to "instantiate" a variable in Excel VBa.